# Update profiled on User object if it is null

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to insert a default profileid when the user is created without this information.

```
trigger atualizaProfile on User (before insert) {
profile pp=[select id, name from Profile where name='ServiceDesk Client' LIMIT 1];

for(User u:trigger.new){
    if(u.ProfileId == null){
        u.profileId = pp.id;
        u.Title = 'teste';

    }
}
```

}

When I test, it always returns an error that the profile was not filled.
[image]

What am I failing to do?

Comment: why not just coerce the profile in a before save flow (or trigger) to `ServiceDesk Client` if role is entered as `HelpDesk Staff`? - that is, override whatever is entered

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that run before triggers do. Namely Page-level validation and system validation rules.

Page-level validation covers fields marked as "required" on page layouts, and these do not apply when performing DML on a record from Apex (or workflow/pb/flow field update actions).

System validation covers things like fields marked as "unique" or "required" as part of the field metadata, and these cannot be bypassed.

Although profileId doesn't appear to be required at the field level (see [the SOAP API docs for User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)), if you try to run the following via Anonymous Apex, it'll tell you that profileId is a required field

```java
System.savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
insert new User(
    Username = 'abc@company.com',
    Alias = 'abc',
    TimezoneSIDKey = 'America/Chicago',
    LocaleSIDKey = 'en_US',
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
    Email = 'abc@company.com',
    LastName = 'person'
);
Database.rollback(sp);
```

So it is required at the field metadata level. If you want to get around this for other objects, you'd need to override the "New" button/action for the object so that you have control over the `save()` method and can do work before performing DML (or calling the standard `save()` method).

User does not allow you to do this.

About the only option available to you is to make a custom Visualforce page or Lightning Web Component that you can provide to your users and train them to use instead of the normal flow (that being Setup -> Manage Users -> Users, and then click the "New User" button).